# Before Insert Trigger SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, triggers, insert

I have two identical tables, `I_Subject` and `I_Temp_Subject` and I want to copy the `Temp_Subject` table to the `Subject` table. `I_Temp_Subject` is used by Simple Users and `I_Subject` is used by the Admin. The Admin can insert new records directly to `I_Subject` and validates the content of `I_Temp_Subject`.

Both table IDs are set to auto increment. The copy SQL command is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO I_SUBJECT(ID,CATEGORY_ID,USER_NAME,SERIAL_NUMBER,ICON)
SELECT ID,CATEGORY_ID,USER_NAME,SERIAL_NUMBER,ICON FROM I_TEMP_SUBJECT
```

If I do that then the following error occurs:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity
column in table 'I_SUBJECT' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

If I don't include the ID in the above statement then everything is ok except the ID's are not identical.

So I want to include a before insert trigger to check if the insert has null ID then autoincrement (when the Admin inserts directly) else if the insert's ID !=null then copy the ID from the `I_Temp_Subject` (when the Admin validates).

Comment: Mahmoud please edit properly

Comment: i did not found much difference in your editing. Before editing also it was fine

Comment: @Sohail - And what do you think with current edit???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can turn off auto increament by using following statement as

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.<tablename>  ON
 write your insert statement here
```

and then turn off identity insert as
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo. OFF

i.e.

```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.I_SUBJECT  ON
    INSERT INTO I_SUBJECT(ID,CATEGORY_ID,USER_NAME,SERIAL_NUMBER,ICON)
    SELECT ID,CATEGORY_ID,USER_NAME,SERIAL_NUMBER,ICON FROM I_TEMP_SUBJECT
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.I_SUBJECT OFF
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the backup table is to be a direct copy, I'd turn off the autoincrement on that one so that the two will always be in sync.
If that't not the option, turn on identity insert, though I think it'd be unnecessary.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.<tablename> ON
<your insert statements>
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.<tablename> OFF
```